# Grant Kubernetes service account privileges to get pods from all namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I would like to grant a Kubernetes service account privileges for executing `kubectl --token $token get pod --all-namespaces`. I'm familiar with doing this for a single namespace but don't know how to do it for all  (including new ones that may be created in the future and without granting the service account [full admin privileges](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/44894)).

Currently I receive this error message:

> Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User
>   "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:test" cannot list resource
>   "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope

What (cluster) roles and role bindings are required?

**UPDATE** Assigning role `view` to the service with the following `ClusterRoleBinding` works and is a step forward. However, I'd like to confine the service account's privileges further to the minimum required.

```
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test
  namespace: kube-system
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: view
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

The service account's token can be extracted as follows:

```
secret=$(kubectl get serviceaccount test -n kube-system -o=jsonpath='{.secrets[0].name}')
token=$(kubectl get secret $secret -n kube-system -o=jsonpath='{.data.token}' | base64 --decode -)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Follow the below yamls and create test serviceaccount.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: default

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]


kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: test
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: pod-reader
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

deploy test pod from the below sample

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    run: test
  name: test
spec:
  serviceAccountName: test
  containers:
  - args:
    - sleep
    - "10000"
    image: alpine
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: test
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 100Mi
```

2. Install curl and kubectl

```
kubectl exec test apk add curl
kubectl exec test -- curl -o /bin/kubectl https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.12.0/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
kubectl exec test -- sh -c 'chmod +x /bin/kubectl'
```

3. You should be able to list the pods from all namespaces from the test pod

```
master $ kubectl exec test -- sh -c 'kubectl get pods --all-namespaces'
NAMESPACE     NAME                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
app1          nginx-6f858d4d45-m2w6f           1/1     Running   0          19m
app1          nginx-6f858d4d45-rdvht           1/1     Running   0          19m
app1          nginx-6f858d4d45-sqs58           1/1     Running   0          19m
app1          test                             1/1     Running   0          18m
app2          nginx-6f858d4d45-6rrfl           1/1     Running   0          19m
app2          nginx-6f858d4d45-djz4b           1/1     Running   0          19m
app2          nginx-6f858d4d45-mvscr           1/1     Running   0          19m
app3          nginx-6f858d4d45-88rdt           1/1     Running   0          19m
app3          nginx-6f858d4d45-lfjx2           1/1     Running   0          19m
app3          nginx-6f858d4d45-szfdd           1/1     Running   0          19m
default       test                             1/1     Running   0          6m
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-g7l6n         1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   coredns-78fcdf6894-r87mx         1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   etcd-master                      1/1     Running   0          32m
kube-system   kube-apiserver-master            1/1     Running   0          32m
kube-system   kube-controller-manager-master   1/1     Running   0          32m
kube-system   kube-proxy-vnxb7                 1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   kube-proxy-vwt6z                 1/1     Running   0          33m
kube-system   kube-scheduler-master            1/1     Running   0          32m
kube-system   weave-net-d5dk8                  2/2     Running   1          33m
kube-system   weave-net-qjt76                  2/2     Running   1          33m
```

Answer (score 2):

`ClustRole` & `ClusterRoleBinding` are correct when you need all namespaces, just shrink down the permissions:

```
kind: ServiceAccount
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: all-ns-pod-get
  namespace: your-ns

---

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: all-ns-pod-get
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]

---

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: all-ns-pod-get
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: all-ns-pod-get
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: all-ns-pod-get
```

Then all pods in a namespace `your-ns` will get a k8s token automatically mounted. You can use bare kubectl or k8s sdk inside a pod without passing any secrets. Note that you **don't** need to pass `--token`, just run the command in a pod within the namespace where you created that ServiceAccount.

Here's a good article explaining the concepts https://medium.com/@ishagirdhar/rbac-in-kubernetes-demystified-72424901fcb3