# Possibility to grant to a kubernetes serviceAccount role and clusterRole RBAC

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

How would it be the best way to grant to a serviceAccount role and clusterRole access?

In my case I would like to grant role access to create, edit and list some secrets, and clusterRole access to list all the volumes in all the namespaces.

Comment: It is not possible to grant a permission to list "some" secrets in a project. It's all or none.

Comment: You can find a similar example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55594676/9164810) answer: it deals with pods instead of secrets.